# VelocityTemplate : How to avoid re-loading of navigation bar while using #parse()

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, velocity

I have good knowledge of java but 0 knowledge of Velocity. I have a task in which I have to stop collapsing of dropdown options of navigation bar. First I thought its a twitter bootstrap issue (collapsing dropdown) but then i realize that every dropdown-option on which I am clicking, is loading the entire page including the navigation bar and that's why dropdown is closing every time .

So lets say I have a page **sample.html** having **#parse("common.vm.html")** inside it and page **common.vm.html** having **#parse("header.vm.html")** inside it; **header.vm.html** is the page where I have my navigation bar implementation.

Comment: If you don't want than you shouldn't load the all page, how do you load the page now?

Comment: I have a page sample.html having #parse("common.vm.html") inside it and page common.vm.html having #parse("header.vm.html") inside it; header.vm.html is the page where I have my navigation bar implementation. So I think #parse() is loading the full page. Is there anyway to avoid reloading of navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

You must realize that Velocity evaluates on the server side, so can only happen on a page reload.

If you only want to reload a **part** of the page, use ajax calls from the javascript side.

For instance, using jquery:

```
$('.dropdown_option').click(function()
{
    $('#dynamic_content').load('/path/to/dynamic/part.vm.html');
});
```